# Excel VBA store only selected Files in Array (not all in folder) and loop through them if at least one file was selected

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, object

Actually, I've got 3 questions:

1. How to store File Objects (with all its properties) in an Array?
2. How to loop through this Array with File Objects?
3. How to stop the code if no File Object exists in this Array?

I know how to loop through **all** files in a selected folder:

```
Sub selectAllFilesInFolder()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fol As folder
    Dim fil As File
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim fStr As String

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    
    fStr = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    Set fol = FSO.getFolder(fStr)
    
    For Each fil In fol.Files
        'do something eg. rename
        fil.Name = "NewFilename_" & fil.Name
    Next
    
    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

My current code is longer than this example and currently throws all kind of errors.
I didn't post all the code because I want to start from scratch with following requirements:

A macro-enabled Excel file (*.xlsm) with three buttons that do the following:

1. select a folder and store **all files** as File System Objects in a global (or Public) Array (which can later be accessed from any other Subroutine. A previously created Array with File Objects should be cleared first)
2. select a folder and store **only selected files** as File System Objects in a global (or Public) Array (which can later be accessed from any other Subroutine. A previously created Array with File Objects should be cleared first)
3. loop through the previously created Array with File Objects and do something, but do nothing if this Array is empty or doesn't contain any File Objects

I've already searched the web and currently there are 73 tabs opened in my browser, each one showing a tutorial, forum or blog post, a YouTube video or anything related.

Unfortunately I didn't find any code snipped that could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

### Create and Use an Array of File Objects

- The code uses late binding, so there is no need for creating library references.
- `TESTcreateFileObjects` calls `createFileObjects` creating an array of file objects and continues working with them (writes some properties to the `Immediate` window).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTcreateFileObjects()
    Dim FileObjects As Variant: FileObjects = createFileObjects()
    If Not IsEmpty(FileObjects) Then
        Dim Item As Variant
        For Each Item In FileObjects
            ' There are 12 properties, some of them pretty useless.
            With Item
                Debug.Print .Name, .Size, .DateCreated
            End With
        Next Item
    'Else ' 'FileObjects' is empty (no files).
    End If
End Sub

Function createFileObjects() As Variant
    Dim FolderPath As Variant ' Can be 'False' if 'FileDialog' canceled.
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    If FolderPath <> False Then
        Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim fsoFile As Object
        With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
            For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
                .Add fsoFile
            Next fsoFile
            If .Count > 0 Then
                createFileObjects = .ToArray
            'Else ' No files (added to 'ArrayList' object).
            End If
        End With
    'Else ' 'FileDialog' canceled.
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I get a Run-time error '5' when Cancel button is pressed.
- Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

Any ideas how deal with it?

If I add an error handler an error is thrown even when I select a folder

Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/r0jQMXxi

Comment: That's out of the scope of your question and my answer which returns objects not file names.